# Why isn't the PageDown Editor triggering Knockout value update when using the button bar?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, custom-binding, pagedown

I am having a problem getting the knockout model to update when a user uses the PageDown button bar to make changes to the editor text. Any typing, pasting, or cutting works fine but the button bar actions do not.

I have tried adding a `hook` for `onPreviewRefresh` to the editor but that never seems to fire.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/vaako62z/1/) showing the issue. If you type `test` into the editor, `test` will show up in the preview section. However, if you type `test` into the editor and then use the menu bar to make `test` bold then the preview section does not see this update until you type another character.

This is the custom binding that I am using to initialize the PageDown editor:

```
var ME = {};
ME.MarkdownConverter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
ME.MarkdownCounter = 0;

ko.bindingHandlers.markdownEditor = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ++ME.MarkdownCounter;
        // Create the elements needed for a new PageDown editor.
        $(element).append($('<div id="wmd-button-bar-' + ME.MarkdownCounter + '" class="wmd-button-bar"></div>'));
        $(element).append($('<textarea id="wmd-input-' + ME.MarkdownCounter + '" class="wmd-input"></textarea>'));

        // Make sure the textarea is properly binded up so that the view model is updated.
        var newBindings = { textInput: valueAccessor };
        ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode($('#wmd-input-' + ME.MarkdownCounter)[0], newBindings, viewModel);

        // Create the editor and apply to the new elements ensuring that we detect all
        // changes from the wmd-button-bar.
        var editor = new Markdown.Editor(ME.MarkdownConverter, "-" + ME.MarkdownCounter);
        editor.hooks.chain("onPreviewRefresh", function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            debugger;
            value($('#wmd-input-' + ME.MarkdownCounter).val());
        });
        editor.run();

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true }; 
    }
};
```

Comment: As a workaround you can subscribe on the `.wmd-button` buttons click event and do an update there: http://jsfiddle.net/uvL85909/ By the way the original code is working in IE10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value update isn't triggered because the value is set programmatically, which doesn't trigger the textarea's change event.

The `onPreviewRefresh` event is not triggered because there is no preview element. As a workaround you can add the element and hide it:

```
var ME = {};
ME.MarkdownConverter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
ME.MarkdownCounter = 0;

ko.bindingHandlers.markdownText = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).addClass('markdown-text');
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
        $(element).html(ME.MarkdownConverter.makeHtml(valueUnwrapped));
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.markdownEditor = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ++ME.MarkdownCounter;
        // Create the elements needed for a new PageDown editor.
        $(element).append($('<div id="wmd-button-bar-' + ME.MarkdownCounter + '" class="wmd-button-bar"></div>'));
        $(element).append($('<textarea id="wmd-input-' + ME.MarkdownCounter + '" class="wmd-input"></textarea>'));        
        // if no preview element is found, onPreviewRefresh is not triggered
        $(element).append('<div style="display: none" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview" id="wmd-preview-' + ME.MarkdownCounter + '"></div>');

        var $input = $('#wmd-input-' + ME.MarkdownCounter);

        // Make sure the textarea is properly binded up so that the view model is updated.
        var newBindings = { textInput: valueAccessor };
        ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode($input[0], newBindings, viewModel);

        // Create the editor and apply to the new elements ensuring that we detect all
        // changes from the wmd-button-bar.
        var editor = new Markdown.Editor(ME.MarkdownConverter, "-" + ME.MarkdownCounter);
        editor.hooks.chain("onPreviewRefresh", function () {
            $input.change();
        });
        editor.run();

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true }; 
    }
};

var vm = { noteText: ko.observable('') };
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/vaako62z/3/